# Wear 6 different hats on 6 consecutive days for 'It Ain’t Easy Being Cheesy'?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Will I get *'It Ain’t Easy Being Cheesy'* hat only when we wear 6 different hats on 6 different UTC days (any 6 days during Winter Bash) or 6 consecutive days?

May be I missed to change my hat on this weekend and I didn't receive this hat.

Comment: I think, It Means six different days. Because, They didn't mention the consecutive days.

Comment: It also mentions "the hat rack on this site" so I believe you also need to be careful to launch the "hat rack" from the same "site" each time e.g. always stack overflow OR always meta stack exchange..

Answer (score 5):

According to the [winter bash](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) website, it says the following:

[image]

which means all you need is to have 6 hats and just wear one hat each day, no need for them to be consecutive days though.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means (not copied, my explanation):

> Wear six hats, and every day have another hat being put on (no need to be consecutive)

So simply do the above will work.